# Javascript Change button text when my div contain all 5 pieces of image

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have 5 pieces of a image in a container which i have to drag and drop in another container to complete the image. After the image is dropped in another container it will stick to the previous image present in this container. Once all the 5 pieces are collected in 2nd container and image is complete i want to change the text of button present in second container from start to end.

How i can figure out image is complete so that i can change a button value ?
http://jsfiddle.net/binit/JnYB9/

**JavaScript**

```
$(function() {

$( "#sortable1" ).sortable({
 connectWith: "div"
 });

$( "#sortable2" ).sortable({
 connectWith: "div",
 change: function( event, ui ) {
     var theID = ui.item.attr('id');
     ui.item.addClass(theID + '-style');
     }
});


});
```

**CSS**

```
.north-img-style { position:absolute;top: 280px;left: 850px;}  
.south-img-style { position:absolute;top: 515px;left: 848px;}
.east-img-style {  position:absolute;top: 280px;left: 1190px;}
.west-img-style {  position:absolute;top: 278px;left: 853px;}
.center-img-style {position:absolute;top: 378px;left: 1050px;}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="row-fluid" >
<div class="span4">
<div class="span1"></div>
<div id="sortable1" class="well span10">

    <h6 class='bg-title'><img src="/static/images/icons/Pocket.png" alt="collect"  style="height:50px"> &nbsp;&nbsp;Collect image parts</h6>
    <hr>
    <span class="form-group label span3" >1st &nbsp;&nbsp;<i class="input-icon fui-image"></i></span>
    <img id="north-img"  src="{% static 'images/demo/north.png' %}" >
    <span class="form-group label span3" >2nd &nbsp;&nbsp;<i class="input-icon fui-image"></i></span>
    <img id="south-img"  src="{% static 'images/demo/south.png' %}" >
    <span class="form-group label span3" >3rd &nbsp;&nbsp;<i class="input-icon fui-image"></i></span>
    <img id="east-img"  src="{% static 'images/demo/east.png' %}" >
    <span class="form-group label span3" >4th &nbsp;&nbsp;<i class="input-icon fui-image"></i></span>
    <img id="west-img"   src="{% static 'images/demo/west.png' %}" >
    <span class="form-group label span3" >5th &nbsp;&nbsp;<i class="input-icon fui-image"></i></span>
    <img id="center-img"  src="{% static 'images/demo/center.png' %}" >
</div>

</div>
<div id="sortable2"  class="well span7" style="height:800px">
<span class='bg-title'><img src="/static/images/icons/save.png" alt="save" style="height:50px"> &nbsp;&nbsp;Save your image</span>
<hr>
 <a id="btn-start" href="/dashboard/save/" class="btn btn-primary btn-embossed">Start</a>
</div>
<div class="span1"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: What is the exact question? Do you have to figure out when the image is complete or how to change the text?

Comment: Yes I want to figure out when the image is complete. if it is complete then i want to change the button text

Comment: Without images it's very hard for us to see what's going on on jsfiddle. Please upload images to a public server and update source here.

Comment: Also are you trying to do something like this? http://innovativephp.com/demo/puzzles/

Comment: I have added the JSFiddle link to my question

Answer (score 0):

The API has the [`receive`-event](http://api.jqueryui.com/sortable/#event-receive). According to the description - it is exactly what you need.

If I were doing this I would count the image pieces on page load and store it in a variable. And then - each time I receive a piece - I would increment another variable and compare it with the first. If the numbers get equal - all the parts have been received.

Also [the API](http://api.jqueryui.com/sortable/) provides some other useful methods and events. Consider having a look.